# How can I find MvcSiteMapProvider.pdb version 2.0.0

Tags: asp.net, version, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

I have googled for getting `MvcSiteMapProvider.pdb` `version 2.0.0` but I couldn't find it.

The lowest version that I could find is `2.3.1` in https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcSiteMapProvider/2.3.1

[image: MvcSiteMapProvider.dll Version 2.0.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orignal [announcement](https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/06/16/aspnet-mvc-mvcsitemapprovider-20-is-out!.html) of the version `2.0.0` release shows that the project was being hosted on CodePlex at that time.

*Lateron the project moved to [Github](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider), but it looks like not all versions were included.*

Luckily the orignal [CodePlex](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mvcsitemap) page contains a [download archive](https://codeplexarchive.blob.core.windows.net/archive/projects/mvcsitemap/mvcsitemap.zip) link to a `.zip` file that includes these missing versions; also the `2.0.0` version, including the compiled `.dll` and `.pdb` files.

**Steps**

1. Unzip the `mvcsitemap.zip` file
2. Go to the `releases` folder.
3. The `releaseList.json` file in that `releases` folder contains the `json` below.

---

```
{
    "Id": "6",
    "Name": "MvcSiteMapProvider 2.0.0",
    "DevelopmentStatus": "Stable",
    "Description": "This is the first release for MvcSiteMapProvider version 2.0.\n\n* It is not backwards compatible with older MvcSiteMapProvider versions. *",
    "ReleasedDatge": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "ModifiedDate": "2010-06-15T05:55:44.23-07:00",
    "Files": [
        {
            "Id": "fe1d566d-937c-4e4b-9aac-fba4c1c4869b",
            "FileName": "MvcSiteMapProvider 2.0.0.zip",
            "Url": "./6/fe1d566d-937c-4e4b-9aac-fba4c1c4869b",
            "Type": "Application",
            "UploadDate": "2010-06-15T05:55:43.027-07:00"
        },
        {
            "Id": "56c22bcd-36bc-4734-84d6-a63502bbb2a4",
            "FileName": "MvcSiteMapProvider 2.0.0 Sample Application.zip",
            "Url": "./6/56c22bcd-36bc-4734-84d6-a63502bbb2a4",
            "Type": "Example",
            "UploadDate": "2010-06-15T05:55:43.06-07:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

4. The `json` above shows you need to rename the file `fe1d566d-937c-4e4b-9aac-fba4c1c4869b` in the folder with name `6` to a `.zip` file, e.g. `MvcSiteMapProvider 2.0.0.zip`.
5. The unzipped `MvcSiteMapProvider 2.0.0.zip` file contains both the `MvcSiteMapProvider.dll` and its corresponding `MvcSiteMapProvider.pdb` files.

---

A picture:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I could only find a Github link to this, which is https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider. I do suggest reading the [ReadME](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/README.md), which will tell you what to do to install MvcSiteMapProvider. If you don't want to go over the entire README, here's the link to all the packages: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=MvcSiteMapProvider. Choose the one you need, follow the instructions and then you will be good to go.